# How to access to an adapter in an Activity when the adapter is created in a class which is called from the Activity?

Tags: android, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

In an Android application, there are the following items:

`Activity_A` (Activity) ,

`Java_C_file_A` (Class which is used in Activity_A) ,

`GridView_A` (dynamically created Gridview inside Java_C_file_A) ,

`CustomAdapter_A` (CustomAdapter for GridView_A)

Now when an item in `GridView` is clicked, I utilize interface to identify the item in `Activity_A`
Then I change the data for `CustomAdapter_A` and I need to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `Activity_A`

But since `CustomAdapter_A` is created in `Java_C_file_A` (which is outside of `Activity_A`), then I don't have access to `CustomAdapter_A` inside `Activity_A`
And I can't use `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside `Activity_A` as a result

How can I have access to `CustomAdapter_A` inside `Activity_A` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create getter for `CustomAdapter_A` inside `Java_C_file_A` class and you will have object of `Java_C_file_A` in your `Activity_A`. Here is sample code to access adapter

In Activity_A

```
Java_C_file_A javaCFileA = new Java_C_file_A();
CustomAdapter_A customAdapter = javaCFileA.getCustomAdapter();
```

Comment: ok, true , what if there would be Java_C_file_B too which is called from Java_C_file_A and CustomAdapter_A would be called from Java_C_file_B instead of Java_C_file_A?

Comment: Then you can access adapter from Java_C_file_B to Java_C_file_A